# jquery datatables button new window open with css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Basically, I just want a button that links to a different page on my site but I want to keep the current CSS and style of TableTools buttons from datatables.net, I didn't want to go fooling around in CSS to mimic something if there is a built in way for me to do it with TableTools.

name of my class is "basic-modal" and i have try in html format link and work open new window modal for this code,

```
 <a href="#" class="basic-modal">Modal Two</a></li>
```

the problem is when i want to add link in datatables button. this is my code

```
 "aButtons": [   
               {
                 "sExtends": "ajax",
                 "sButtonText": "Add SKOM ",
                 "fnClick": function ( nButton, oConfig, oFlash )
                  {
                    window.open('jex5.htm','mywindow','width=400,height=200,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100');
                  }
               } 
             ]
```

it wont load css class because im using window.open to load new window.
is there any sugestion and solution for insert my css class in new window link ?

Comment: Um, add the css to that page to start?

Comment: what does **`insert my css class in new window link`** mean?